# Many things in PHP are printing 0 or 1 on hosting server

Tags: php

I wonder why some things are automatically "echo"-ing `0` or `1` on my hosting server.

For example this code outputs `0`

```
<?php

class Test
{
      public function __construct()
      {
      }
}

$t = new Test;

?>
```

Comment: I know. It's just on my hosting server.

Comment: It outputs `0` even if I just write only `<?php $var = "test"; ?>`

Comment: You should make a simple test page that shows that and contact your host about it..

Comment: If I send a header like `print("sent");` in the beginning, then `0` and `1` are not outputed anymore. So, this does not need a solution, my question is `why it happens like this?` is there some sort of configuration for such behavior? I just wondered.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server misconfiguration by your web host. Inform your web host about this issue and they should be able to fix it. On a properly configured system this code should not produce any output.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I believe that has something to do with the PHP configuration. It either outputs false or true. I would recommend checking your php.ini file in order to see if there is a setting enabled for default boolean value of the variable.